# $\{0,1\}^*$ vs $\{0,1\}^+$ vs $(0 \cup 1)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I understand that $(0 U 1)^*$ is the set of all binary strings. However, what do the other two expressions create?

Could someone please provide examples of what  strings these languages would accept?

$L = \{0,1\}^*$

$L = \{0,1\}^+$

Comment: This is a very basic question that could be answered by any textbook or any set of lecture notes on the subject. Did you do any research before asking here?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Very lost in my undergrad automata theory course. Came here for help and not ridicule.

Comment: Terminology: A language is defined to be a set of strings, so a language cannot "accept" a string. Any string is either a member of a language or is not. BTW, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some abuse of notation going on. There are regular expressions and there are sets of strings.

$\{0, 1\}^*$ is the set of all binary strings. This is (rarely) used to mean the regular expression matching all binary strings.

$(0 \cup 1)^*$ is the regular expression matching all binary strings.

$(0 \cup 1)^+$ is the regular expression matching all non-empty binary strings.

$\{0, 1\}^+$ is (rarely used) to denote the regular expression that matches all non-empty binary strings (same as $(0 \cup 1)^+$). It might be used in some places to denote the set of all non-empty binary strings, but I never personally saw this usage.

Comment: Weird, my Formal Languages professor exclusively used {0,1}* and {0,1}+

Comment: @FrostyStraw. In my classes I frequently use $\{0,1\}^*$. After all, the Kleene star is defined on languages and $\{0,1\}$ is certainly a language. I don't often have a reason to use $\{0,1\}^+$ though I would if necessary.